# Is there any automated quick way of cartoonizing in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I found [this](http://www.vectorportraits.com/) website which does what I want but it seems very tedious.  I would have thought Photoshop would have a way of automating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This guide here](http://www.photoshopcstutorial.com/photo-effects-tutorials/cartoon-drawing-tutorial.php) does it in "four" steps:

Cartoon Drawing Photoshop Images Effect

- Open an image that you would like to manipulate. Make sure your image is in RGB mode. To check this, go to Image under the menu bar - Mode - RGB Color. 
  Make a duplicate of this layer as you will be working on this layer going forward.

[image]

- Now we will be applying the Poster Edges filter. To do this, go to Filter > Artistic > Poster Edges.
- After the Poster Edges effect, we will Adjust the Brightness & Contrast with the values: Brightness Value: 10 Contrast: 30.

[image]

- Now we will do an artistic cut out effect to give it that cartoon look. Go to Filter > Artistic > Cut Out. And this is what you get!

[image]

Comment: hmm . . following your steps didn't work out quite so well for me. .  the background and the person got blended together . .hmm  . .

Comment: That's why you have to create a duplicate layer, one for the person, one for the background

Comment: i dont see how the duplicate layer helps if the duplicate layer duplicates the background as well.

Comment: *doh* You're right, I was assuming the duplicate layer would have to be of the person and you alter them both in a different way. Though Poster Edges is supposed to seperate the background and the person. That isn't working for you?